# Cannot connect through android device

Tags: android, json, connection

I am having problem to connect to the server via android application which is running on a device. on the device it gives http connection refused error

```
    E/log_tag(31377): Error in http connectionorg.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
E/log_tag(31377): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: `lock == null`...
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect through a local network?

Comment: Show the url you used please.

Comment: basically i have a wampserver on my local matchine and trying to get data from mysql, i am emulating the app on the android device

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/androidbasicinfo/file.php");

Comment: check your manifest for INTERNET permission